# Continuous servo not setting speed correctly

Tags: arduino-uno, continuous-servo

I have two continuous servos connected to my Uno, and I'm running this code on it:

```
leftServo.write(91);
rightServo.write(102);
delay(3000);

leftServo.write(112);
rightServo.write(81);
delay(3000);

leftServo.write(91);
rightServo.write(102);
delay(3000);

int i;
while(1) {
  i++;
}
```

When I run the code, the wheels stop for three seconds (91 and 102 are the zero values for these servos) then they spin for three seconds, then the left servo stops, but the right one only slows down about half way, it doesn't stop, even though the exact same number is used as before.

I can't figure out why this is?

Comment: My first piece of advise would be to dump that function (without the "while(1)" part) into the end of setup() and see what happens.

Comment: Same effect unfortunately

Comment: Have you swapped the motors round to check it's not the hardware? If that's the same try swapping the order of the final leftservo/rightservo commands.

Comment: I have added a delay of 100 ms between servo writes, and that seems to have helped, the zero point for the right servo seems to have moved now though, 106 moves slowly counter-clockwise, and 107 moves slowly clockwise

Comment: I'm leaning toward the conclusion that the problem is with the hardware, probably some noise effecting the servo. Are the motors running on a different supply to the Uno? Have you made sure the grounds are tied together? Have you tried some decoupling caps on the servo power supply? If you have access to one take an oscilloscope to the circuit and check for unwanted noise.

Comment: This is for an assignment, we are given a pre-made shield which we aren't allowed to modify. I'm using a 3A mains adaptor to power the board. Grounds are tied.

Comment: Any chance of getting a scope on the board to check the noise theory? If it's confirmed as definately not noise related I'm running out of ideas. I should be able to spend some more time on this evening, if I find anything relevent I'll get back to you.

Comment: It is possible your zero values are incorrect, but still manage to stop the motors under some circumstances if coming from a previous value which causes the servo amp to decide it is in an anti-hunting "dead band".  Another possibility could be heating from running the motor moving the neutral point, though it seems less likely.  Fundamentally, these continuous-run modifications can be temperamental, as they take something that is supposed to be closed loop and cut the loop open.

Answer (score 2):

Issue was fixed by adding a delay of 100ms between servo writes, smaller values may work, but I haven't tried yet